# How to redraw a diagram with TikZ datavisualization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

The original diagram:

[image: original]

My try:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
            tikz,
            amsmath
           }

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean,
                                          standard labels
                                         },
                       x axis = {
                                 include value = {
                                                  0.35,
                                                  2.15
                                                 },
                                 grid = {minor = {at = {
                                                        1,
                                                        1.5
                                                       }}},
                                 label = $t$
                                },
                       y axis = {
                                 include value = {
                                                  -.25,
                                                  1
                                                 },
                                 label = Schadstoffkonzentration
                                },
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {
                                                         HC,
                                                         CO,
                                                         NO_x
                                                        },
                       style sheet = vary dashing,
                       HC = {label in legend = {text = HC}},
                       CO = {label in legend = {text = CO}},
                       NO_x = {label in legend = {text = NO$_{\text x}$}}
                      ]
    data[set = HC] {
                    var x : interval[.5:2];
                    func y = exp(-3 * \value x) + .15;
                   }
    data[set = CO] {
                    var x : interval[.5:2];
                    func y = exp(-\value x) + .15;}
    data[set = NO_x] {
                      var x : interval[.75:2];
                      func y = ln(\value x) + .15;
                     }
    info {
          \draw
            (visualization cs: x = 1.25, y = .8) node {schadstoffarme Verbrennung};
         };

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: result]
Tasks:

1. Completely remove the ticks.
2. Improve the info.
3. Maybe some optimization of the whole code.

Something like this:

[image: wish]

Also completely different solutions, which solve the whole task are welcome!

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Dat indentation tho...

Comment: Hello @percusse! I don't understand what you mean? Could you please explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, task one is easy, just add `ticks=none`. For the others I have some simple proposals, but I will be happy to respond to feedback. And you should talk to @CarLaTeX, who has a *really* efficient car. ;-)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
            tikz,
            amsmath
           }

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean,
                                          standard labels
                                         },
                       x axis = {
                                 include value = {
                                                  0.35,
                                                  2.15
                                                 },
                                 grid = {minor = {at = {
                                                        1,
                                                        1.5
                                                       }}},
                                 label = $t$,
                                 ticks=none %<-added
                                },
                       y axis = {
                                 include value = {
                                                  -.25,
                                                  1
                                                 },
                                 label = Schadstoffkonzentration,
                                 ticks=none %<-added
                                },
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {
                                                         HC,
                                                         CO,
                                                         NO_x
                                                        },
                       style sheet = vary dashing,
                       HC = {label in legend = {text = HC}},
                       CO = {label in legend = {text = CO}},
                       NO_x = {label in legend = {text = NO$_{\text x}$}}
                      ]
    data[set = HC] {
                    var x : interval[.5:2];
                    func y = exp(-3 * \value x) + .15;
                   }
    data[set = CO] {
                    var x : interval[.5:2];
                    func y = exp(-\value x) + .15;}
    data[set = NO_x] {
                      var x : interval[.75:2];
                      func y = ln(\value x) + .15;
                     }
    info {
          \draw
            (visualization cs: x = 1.25, y = 1.1) node[font=\small] {schadstoffarme Verbrennung};
         };

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]